# Using different color than bootstrap default color scheme - Django Python

Tags: python, html, css, django

Pretty new to Django,
Recently, while building a website using Django, I created the navbar and used bootstrap. Just to make it look better.
However, it seems that I'm forced to use bootstrap default color scheme.

I want to change the navigation bar background color to a color tag, inside the base.html file.

Google left me empty-handed. With many advices on overwriting and adding your custom.css (which a lot of people aware you of doing so as it is not recommended).

I tried adding custom script into the html file, failed.

```
<script>
  .navbar-custom {
   background-color: #9f6967;
  }
</script>
```

I would appreciate help on (maybe) creating a custom.css file.
So far the nav-bar is the default bootstrap navigation bar script from their website.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

Other than dark/light/other colors from the scheme, there isn't any way to add a color tag.
(specific : #9f6967)

Comment: this is not related to django. it's CSS. in the css you could force what you want by writing like `background-color: #9f6967 !important;`

Comment: Yep, if you load something like `custom.css` that redefines the bootstrap colours you want to set, it will work - just make sure you load this _after_ the bootstrap css in the template!

Comment: So just to be clear, using !important will force it right? 
Also, I need to use bootstrap's names?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Mahdi Firouzjah and michjnich advice.
Created a custom.css file,

```
.container-fluid { 
   background-color: #9f6967 !important;
}
```

Inside the template,

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'content.css' %}>
```

Restarted my app and it worked.
Appreciate your help! ;3

Answer (score 0):

A little late but below is my solution for future research...

`pip install django-compressor django-libsass`

Then download the complete bootstrap files (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap), including the scss files and organize them in the structure

```
bootstrap
|____css
|____js
|____scss
```

Add `compressor` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file. Also make sure you have static file settings and compressor settings, something like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
     'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
     ('text/scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
)
```

In your template, load the tag and the scss file to be compiled. Note that the `type` must be the same as that configured in `COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS`

```
{% load static %}
{% load compression %}
{% compress css %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="{% static 'path/to/your/custom.scss' %}">
{%endcompress%}
```

And finally create your `custom.scss` file, follow the documentation available through bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/

Just be careful with the number of functons included in your `custom.scss` file as the compressor will create "cache" file and the more functions imported, the larger the cache file will be, causing delays in loading pages. Here is an example of a `custom.scss`

```
@import "../bootstrap/scss/functions";

$primary: #fd7e14;
$secondary: #707070;

@import "../bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/forms";
```